# How can I make my source adapt to changes in the names of commands in different versions of a package?

Tags: acro, versions

I am trying to compile a document on two systems (one is Overleaf) and they appear to have differences in their texlive installation, specifically in the version of the `acro` package. On one system, I can compile if I use `\acroifusedTF{}`. On the other, I must use `\acifused{}` in the same place. Can I put something in my preamble to the effect of "acifused means acroifusedTF if you can't find acifused"?

I want it to work with the Overleaf compiler to make it easier to share the document. I want it to work locally because local editing and compilation is faster sometimes. I use git to keep them synchronized. I tried the 2020 and 2019 texlive options in Overleaf.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}
\author{tester}
\date{date}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{DTS}{short=DTS, long=Divertor Thomson Scattering}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Table~\ref{tab:my_label} uses an acronym before it appears in the body.
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & b \\
        \hline
        c & d
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{An acronym is used in the caption of a float before being used in the body: \acroifusedTF{DTS}{\ac{DTS}}{\ac{DTS}\acreset{DTS}}.}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}


Now the acronym is used again, this time in the body, after it was already used in a caption:
\ac{DTS}.
I don't want the acronym to be used up in a float caption before it is used in the body.
Subsequent use: \ac{DTS}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you mentioned using overleaf as well as a local installation: Which version works wich `\acroifusedTF`? If it's the overlaf one, you might want to update your local installation, if it's the local one, you might want to try using overleaf's texlive 2020 again. It should contain a version of `acro`, that works with `\acroifusedTF`. If you can't update (or don't want to), you could use `\usepackage[version=2]{acro}` whenever you compile your code on the system that would prefer `\acroifusedTF` and replace all instances of `\acroifusedTF` with the older `\acifused`.

Comment: @leandriis Controlling installation version is a good idea, but on the other hand, I'd like to be able to have some control in the latex source, too, for reasons including future compatibility and sharing with people on other systems. `\usepackage[version=2]{acro}` is attractive.

Comment: Not just `\acifused` vs. `\acroifusedTF` changed between version 2 and version 3 of the `acro` package. So, instead of redefining a single command, I suggest to make sure all systems/ users involved use the same version of the package.

Comment: Yes, this is good. Setting the version in `\usepackage` is nice for portability, too.

Comment: Ah, but the older version of acro apparently doesn't accept the version option at usepackage. Too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
\providecommand{\acroifusedTF}{\acifused}
```

you can use `\acroifusedTF` even on older systems that define `\acifused`  instead of `\acroifusedTF`. It is just a name change; the functionality has not changed.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question: `\acroifused` should be `\acifused`. `\providecommand` is much more compact than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution based on `\ifcsname`, adding this bit to the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\acifusedadapt}[3]{%
  \ifcsname acifused \endcsname%
    \acifused{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \else%
    \acroifusedTF{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \fi%
}
```

And then using `\acifusedadapt{DTS}{\ac{DTS}}{\ac{DTS}\acreset{DTS}}.}` later, in place of `\acroifusedTF{...}`.